# Mongoose find, multiple fields with one search parametar

Tags: node.js, express

I cant understand why this does not work, I am sending input through :searchTerm and firstly trying to find the term in the name section of the DB if there's not data returned I am trying to find the same term in the surname section of the DB.
I want to query the db firstly for the name if there is no name found I am trying to look for the surname. 
Can someone explain why the code does not work, it is working like couple of times then it does not return anything.

```
   app.get('/api/find/:searchTerm', (req, res) => {
      var counter = 0
      Employee.find({ name: req.params.searchTerm }).then(findedData => {
        if(findedData) { res.json(findedData) }
        if(findedData === undefined || findedData == 0){ counter = 1 }
      })
      if(counter = 1) {
        Employee.find({ surName: req.params.searchTerm }).then(surnameData => {
        res.json(surnameData)
        })
      }
    });
```

it works when I querying for the first name, but it does not work for the surName.
Thanks

Comment: `if(counter = 1) ` ?? should be `if(counter == 1)` ?

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: app.get('/api/find/:searchTerm', (req, res) => {
  Employee.find({ name: req.params.searchTerm }).then(findedData => {
    if(findedData) {
      res.json(findedData)
    } else {
      console.log('works');
      Employee.find({ surName: req.params.searchTerm }).then(findedDataSurName => {
      res.json(findedDataSurName)
    });
    }



  });
});

Comment: for some reason the if else don't work

Comment: Hi @n2kin if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it] (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution 
 and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

mongoose find returns an empty array, so we need to check findedData.length > 0 if something there.

So you should do like this:

```
app.get("/api/find/:searchTerm", (req, res) => {

  Employee.find({ name: req.params.searchTerm }).then(findedData => {
    if (findedData.length > 0) {
      return res.json(findedData);
    }

    Employee.find({ surName: req.params.searchTerm }).then(surnameData => {
      return res.json(surnameData);
    });
  });
});
```

And with error handling:

```
app.get("/api/find/:searchTerm", (req, res) => {
  Employee.find({ name: req.params.searchTerm })
    .then(findedData => {
      if (findedData.length > 0) {
        return res.json(findedData);
      }

      Employee.find({ surName: req.params.searchTerm })
        .then(surnameData => {
          return res.json(surnameData);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return res
            .status(500)
            .send("Something went wrong with surname search");
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("Something went wrong with name search");
    });
});
```

Comment: @n2kin great, please dont forget to mark as answer.